# Saving an image from an URL to a local file in C#

Tags: c#

I have the following code which save an image with an URL to a local file.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://images.craigslist.org/00o0o_kFhPDdTGf2e_600x450.jpg", "c:\\Tmp\test.jpg");
}
```

But when I run it, I get an exception. It said 'An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
When I see that exception in deubgger. It said 'Illegal characters in path.'

I check that url is valid via my browser. So what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use, @ symbol like this

```
      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(@"http://images.craigslist.org/00o0o_kFhPDdTGf2e_600x450.jpg",                                @"c:\\Tmp\test.jpg");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains a tab character: `\t`. Escape the second backslash: `"C:\\Tmp\\test.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

```
"c:\\Tmp\test.jpg"
```

You forgot to escape the second `t`.

You should either use `@"c:\Tmp\test.jpg"` or `"c:\\Tmp\\test.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Just put an @ symbol before the path names.

```
       using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile(@"http://images.craigslist.org/00o0o_kFhPDdTGf2e_600x450.jpg", @"c:\Tmp\test.jpg");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains `\t` which is an illegal path character. Back slash is a reserved character in C#, for characters like tab and line ending, and so must be escaped.

You can either make it a double back slash `"C:\\Tmp\\test.jpg"`, or escape the whole string with an @ character at the beginning `@"C:\Tmp\test.jpg"`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"C:\\Tmp\\test.jpg"
```

for your filename

Treat those like any other string. The first backslash is the escape character, the second is to recognize the backslash